# Jivatma and Paramatma are totally seperate

Tags: vaishnavism, advaita, brahman, dvaita

Sri [Sri Vijayeendra Tirtha](http://www.raghavendramutt.org/about/shri-vijayeendra-teertharu) (Paramaguru of Sri Raghavendra Tirtha)

Explains through a simple analogy or Upamaanam. Â Mahan Sri Vijayeendra Tirthar jestingly asks: Â "Will a mother willingly and knowingly give poison to her child and, then also give an anti-dote for the poison? The answer is NO. Similarly, would anyone knowingly enter/ jumpÂ into dirt and then clean oneselves up from dirt? The answer is NO. So, why would the Lord create Jivatmas and knowingly put Avidya, Agyanam into them that then makes them think that they are different from the Paramatma which supposedly they are not, Then why would the Lord also give them ways (i.e., study of scriptures, atma vichaara etc. etc.) by sending a messenger, as an anti-dote to overcome this Avidya? Similarly, why would the Jivaatmas enter into dirt knowingly if they were originally unsullied that makes them deluded and, then later study scriptures to realise that they are the same as Brahman??

So definitely Jivatma and Paramatma are totally seperate . Whats your comments?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Unfortunately, as your question stands it's likely to attract opinion-based answers, since different people have different opinions on the relation between Jivatmas and Paramatma.  But you can edit your question to make it more of a question and less of a challenge to other people.  For instance, you can ask a more neutrally worded question about what Advaitins believe is the purpose of Jivatmas having avidya.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Thank you. My question is not related to attract opinion based answers, instead i am looking for more comments based on my example, so that it leads in gaining correct knowledge and not avidya.

Comment: As I said, you should rephrase it so that it's less like a request for comments and more like an actual question.

Comment: Dear friend, it seems you are looking to start an argument between Dvaita and Advaita. There are different paths for different people. Not every path is suitable for all. If you believe in Dvaita, well and good. If you believe in Advaita, even then well and good. All paths lead to the same goal, happiness. Dvaitins say that Advaita is totally illogical. I assure you that many advaitins would say that Dvaita is totally immature and childish. This is all God's play. His Leela. All paths are valid. There is no right and no wrong path. All the best!!

Comment: Dear KS, thank you for the suggession. Dear all. I am here definitely to receive knowledge. Not to hurt any one's feeling. I am here to recieve both negative and positive comments, answers, views. I humbly respect each and every words. Dear sai as you said everything is god's play. Then why we have to consider the actions is "our's". It is 'he' who gives mind to think, to do acions. Thank you

Comment: @RaghavendraAcharaya Again, your question is still just in the form of asking people to comment on something.  You're still not asking a concrete question.  If you want I can rewrite your question to make it acceptable.

Comment: yes it is 'He' who gives mind to think. So use it to think good positive thoughts that unite people, rather than arguments and fights which divide the community. :) The knowledge that 'He is the doer, and I am an instrument' is one that Unites, one that makes everyone happy. It is not a convenient excuse to follow our own prejuidices. It comes from the depths of realization and not from the shore of argumentation. Anyway since you said that you are genuinely looking for answers, the answer to your question is that Avidhya is itself an illusion and does not exist in Brahman, All the best.